# Substracting a character vector to a character column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am doing an analysis of some subtitles and I have manage to clean and count the frequency. Now I want to delete all the stopwords (coming with the "tm" package).

Here is the example of the data:

```
words2 <- c("a", "be", "am", "you", "lannister", "wolf", "angry", "scandals", "should", "me")
frequency2 <- c(12,10,15, 20, 5, 10,8,3,9,20)
stopwordslst <- c("i","me","my","myself","we","our","ours","ourselves","you","your","yours","yourself","it","its","they","them","thei","theirs","themselves", "what",
"those","am","is","are","be","been","being","have","has","does","did","doing","would","should")
```

so I try to make a for loop, the idea was to make logical and then delete all the true ones. but I can't find the right way to do it so it keep the false in the same structure in the data.frame.

Here is what I try:

```
for(i in words){
if(i == stopwordslst[]){
  (data1[-i,])
 }
}
```

Expected results the same dataframe but like this:

```
words       frequency
lannister   5
wolf        10
angry       8
scandals    3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do for loop? Have a look at `%in%` as in `words2[!words2 %in% stopwordslst]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sotos mentioned, you can use `%in%` along with `!` to get the words which you want to include and use the same indexes to select the frequency.

```
df <- data.frame(words = words2[!words2 %in% stopwordslst],
                 frequency = frequency2[!words2 %in% stopwordslst])
df
# words frequency
#1         a        12
#2 lannister         5
#3      wolf        10
#4     angry         8
#5  scandals         3
```

Note: You do not have 'a' in your `stopwordslst`, so it is included.

---

Or a little cleaner,

```
idx <- !words2 %in% stopwordslst
df <- data.frame(words = words2[idx],frequency = frequency2[idx])
```

Answer (score 0):

Iteratively removing the words of `df` occuring in `stopwordlst` works for me.

```
df = data.frame(words=words2,frequency=frequency2)
df = df[(sapply(c(1:nrow(df)),FUN = function(x){sum(df$words[x]==stopwordslst)})==0),]
> df
      words frequency
5 lannister         5
6      wolf        10
7     angry         8
8  scandals         3
```